# Integrating PDFJS in Angular

Tags: angular, pdf.js, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I'm creating a new component in Angular to show PDF file  , in order to that ,I used ng2-pdfjs-viewer following these steps in the link "https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdfjs-viewer" but it's not working. I don't know exactly where the problem.
here the html component:

```html
<ng2-pdfjs-viewer 
  #pdfViewer
 [pdfJsFolder]="'https://www.emse.fr/~picard/cours/1A/java/livretJava.pdf'"
  [externalWindow]="true"
  [downloadFileName]="'mytestfile.pdf'"
  [openFile]="false"
  [viewBookmark]="false"
  [download]="false">
 </ng2-pdfjs-viewer>
```

Can anyone explain where is the problem?

I have another Question is it possible to load pdf from an external link for example "D:\file.pdf".

Comment: Do you get any errors? What's the result of your code?

Comment: actually no, i just don't have any view of the pdf file, i mean it should render a view of the " https://www.emse.fr/~picard/cours/1A/java/livretJava.pdf " file, but i don't have any view

Comment: check your browser console to see if there are any errors raising from your code.

Comment: no i didn't find any console error

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? The package you are using is designed for Angular 2 based on it's info and there's another one for Angular 5+ https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer

Comment: I'm using Angular 6, but i guess the problem is not from the version. thanks @FaridRn i will try ng2-pdf-viewer and see if it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation of **`ng2-pdfjs-viewer`**(https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdfjs-viewer),  `[pdfJsFolder]` is used to set path to PDF.JS's web and build folders.

You should use **`pdfSrc`** attribute to set pdf's path. It is mentioned under usage section of documentation

E.g.

**`<ng2-pdfjs-viewer pdfSrc="your pdf file path"></ng2-pdfjs-viewer>`**

The documentation also states that uses Mozilla's PDF.JS behind the scenes.
Irrespective of that, glad you got the issue resolved